# is there a better function than 'computeSVD()' that uses mapreduce in term of execution time?

Tags: python, pyspark

I used the function `computeSVD()` and i used a large matrix on it and the execution time is so long comparing to a function that normaly use mapreduce which normaly makes the execution time better.
i compared these two functions:

```
start_time = time.time()
number_of_documents=200
L,S,R=np.linalg.svd(X)  <--- don't use mapreduce

exemple_three = time.time() - start_time
print("---Exemple three : %s seconds ---" % (exemple_three))
output:
---Exemple three : 5.322664976119995 seconds ---
```

and the second one `computeSVD()`

```
start_time = time.time()

number_of_documents=200
svd = mat.computeSVD(5, computeU=True)  <--- use mapreduce

exemple_two = time.time() - start_time
print("---Exemple one : %s seconds ---" % (exemple_two))
output:
---Exemple one : 252.04261994361877 seconds ---
```

**my goal is a similar function that uses mapreduce**

Comment: I have no idea what the issue is. Seems like you found your answer.

Comment: the thing is i want a function that uses mapreduce but makes the running time better which ```np.linalg.svd(X)```does not  do the job since it doesn't use mapreduce